# Removing Element with Jsoup doesn't work

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

i want to remove some elements (CSS--tags) in the head of a html file.
I tried it like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Element head = doc.head();
Elements headChildren = head.children();
for (Element el : headChildren) {
    if (el.attr("type").contains("text/css") || el.attr("rel").contains("stylesheet")){
       Log.d("HTML", "elements-before: " +  el.nodeName()); //Log prints 7 elments
       el.remove();

    }
}

for (Element el : headChildren ) {
    if (el.attr("type").contains("text/css") || el.attr("rel").contains("stylesheet")){
       Log.d("HTML", "elements-after: " +  el.nodeName()); //Log prints 7 elments again
    }
}
```

I really don't know where my fault is. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the `Element` from the `Document` object where they are located, not the `Elements` collection. Thus, when you print each `Element` the second time, they are still in the `Elements` collection, but not in the `Document`.

The Jsoup classes `Element`, `Comment`, `Document` and so on are all subclasses of the Node class, which represents a node in the DOM tree. The method `remove()` is an inherited method from the `Node` class, and it removes the node from the DOM tree.

Comment: Doh! I still hadn't got there. Well done. @OP: Just do `headChildren = head.children();` again before your second loop to see the difference.