# How to update an Elements so that it does not contain Removed Links?

Tags: java, jsoup

> Note : There is a similar question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548029/removing-element-with-jsoup-doesnt-work).  However, I have reviewed this question and it does not solve my problem.  Please read ahead.

I wrote a  method that attempts to remove certain links from an `Elements`.  I understand that `remove()` removes the `Element` from the `Document` ob where it is located.  However, **how can I update my `Elements` so that it does not contain the removed links?**

Below is my method.

```
public void getLinks(Document site) {

    Elements links = site.select("a[href]");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < links.size() ; i++) {

      String url = links.get(i).attr("abs:href");

      if(url.endsWith("~S1")) {
        System.out.println(url);
      } else {
        links.remove(i); // links still contains removed Element
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watchout! as it is, the loop:  `for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++)`, never takes places because `i < 0` returns `false` just before start looping ...

Comment: You can use neither i<0 nor i>0 , if you use i>0 you  will have a infinite for loop.instead of 0 use another Integer value. Because you can't check the condition with the starting value repeatedly in for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers :)  My problem, however, still remains.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `listIterator`.
You can safely remove elements while iterating through the list (Elements extends ArrayList class)

```
 ListIterator<Element> it = links.listIterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
   Element link = it.next();
   String url = links.get(i).attr("abs:href");
   if(... {// your condition. I can't properly copy, writing from a mobile phone
   link.remove();
   }
 }
```

Remember, that it is not safe to remove elements from list while iterating by means of common `for` operator. Because of reindexing. E.g. you have removed 5-th element, loop counter incremented by 1, you want remove 6-th element, but instead removing 7-th one. List interface do not keep empty indexes, so it will reorganize list of elements immediately after removal operation in favor to hold unbreakable sequence. 
Use for your task `ListIterator` power, which was created for such purposes as removing, bidirectional iterating and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I update my Elements so that it does not contain the removed links?**

[`Elements`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) actually provides several convenience methods that don't require iterating or looping across the child element(s) for this.

Starting html:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div> 
   <a href="foo.html?S1">foo</a> 
   <a href="not_foo.html">not foo</a> 
   <a href="foo2.html?S1">foo2</a> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Get a sample `Elements` obj:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("a");

System.out.println(elements.outerHTML());

...

<a href="foo.html?S1">foo</a>
<a href="not_foo.html">not foo</a>
<a href="foo2.html?S1">foo2</a>
```

To remove the links ending in "S1" from the `Elements` object:

```
elements.removeAll(elements.select("a[href$=S1]"));

System.out.println(elements.outerHTML());

...

<a href="not_foo.html">not foo</a>
```

Alternatively, create a new `Elements` obj that does not contain the links ending in "S1":

```
Elements cleanLinks = elements.not("a[href$=S1]");

System.out.println(cleanLinks.outerHtml());

...

<a href="not_foo.html">not foo</a>
```

---

**Note: Neither `Elements.remove(Collection)` nor `Elements.not(String)` remove the elements from the `Document` object.**